# When tmux is in use, copy/paste from terminal turns tabs to spaces

Tags: tmux

I have a few python scripts that prints data with the tab character '\t' as a delimiter.

This is to allow copying the output of these scripts directly to Google Sheets or Quip.

When I run my script inside Tmux, I see the '\t' being printed on the screen but when I try top copy and paste it onto Google sheets, it no longer act as a delimiter.

Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: You're trying to _copy-and-paste_ from tmux, and expecting it to stay a literal tab? Copy-and-paste isn't exactly part of the contract -- a terminal promises to make things look right on the screen; it doesn't guarantee anything about what it sends to its display layer (and in this case, tmux is your terminal, and gnome-terminal or whatever outer terminal you have is the display layer to that inner terminal) to make that happen.

Comment: ...if you want copy-and-paste to be guaranteed to work right, I'd strongly suggest bypassing your terminal altogether and piping content to `xclip` or a similar tool, as appropriate for whichever platform you're on. tmux itself can be configured to call xclip directly, for that matter. (If you're on Mac, you might want `pbcopy` instead, f/e).

Comment: I'd also consider asking this over at [unix.se] or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) instead of Stack Overflow, being more a question about using UNIX tools than about writing code.